# VPN and Lan visibility

Tags: linux, vpn, pptp

I have enabled VPN pass-through and configured our router to forward pptp port (1723) data to go to our linux server running pppd and pptpd, this works, I can establish the connexion using  my windows 7 laptop (I get a new I.P address and DNS and WINS server addresses), this allows me to view the samba shared files that are held on the VPN server.  However there are some strange points :

I can only connect to VPN server by ssh, not telnet, while I can ping the other servers on the LAN I cannot telnet to them either, again only connect by ssh.

There are no rules in iptables at all and `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` is set to 1 indicating that forwarding is turned on.  Any thoughts?

I should have said I can only ssh as root to the initial VPN server but then I can ssh from there to the other servers.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say I admitted defeat, and installed OpenVPN on the server, you just need to open one port on the firewall and do a bit of configuring which is explained in the ["how-to"](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html), a much easier solution to manage.